# Filter list by list of dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects which contain a DateTimeOffset property.
I want to filter that list so that only objects whose date match one from another list of dates.

For example if the list of objects contain the following date time property:

```
{Test1, 12/1/2020},
{Test2, 12/2/2020},
{Test3, 12/3/2020}
```

and another list

```
12/1/2020
12/2/2020.
```

Only

```
{Test1, 12/1/2020},
{Test2, 12/2/2020}
```

should be returned

Comment: Apparently you already know that you can do that with LINQ, according to the tags. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `Where ()` and `Contains()`

Sample data:

```
var data = new [] {
    new { Name="Test1", Date = new DateTimeOffset(2020,12,1,0,0,0,TimeSpan.Zero) },
    new { Name="Test2", Date = new DateTimeOffset(2020,12,2,0,0,0,TimeSpan.Zero) },
    new { Name="Test3", Date = new DateTimeOffset(2020,12,3,0,0,0,TimeSpan.Zero) },
};

var filter = new[] {
    new DateTimeOffset(2020,12,1,0,0,0,TimeSpan.Zero),
    new DateTimeOffset(2020,12,2,0,0,0,TimeSpan.Zero),
};
```

Filtering:

```
var filteredData = data.Where(p => filter.Contains(p.Date)).ToArray();
```

Comment: When the number of entries of `data` and/or `filter` get higher, it might be worth to turn `filter` into a `HashSet<T>`, where `Contains` should be O(1) instead of O(n) as it is for arrays and lists. Building and filling a set is more costly though, So you might need to do some benchmarking to figure out what the sweetspot is for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
List<DateObject> objectList = new List<DateObject>();

var filteredList = objectList.Where(a => dateList.Contains(a.Date));
```

Check this:

[How to check list A contains any value from list B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376437/how-to-check-list-a-contains-any-value-from-list-b/12377237)