# Filtering or removing array objects from the DTO class object based on an another list in .net

Tags: c#, json, list, linq, asp.net-core

I have below code :

```json
[
    {
        "OrderId": "Order1",
        "filterOrder": [ "ABC", "XYZ" ],
        "Details": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "value": 100,
                "filterDetails": [ "Apples", "Oranges" ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "value": 200,
                "filterDetails": [ "Banana", "Blank" ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "OrderId": "Order2",
        "filterOrder": [ "PQR", "Blank" ],
        "Details": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "value": 100,
                "filterDetails": [ "Apples", "Peaches" ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "value": 200,
                "filterDetails": [ "Banana", "Mango" ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

C# code:

```cs
string i = GetJsonText();
var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(i);
```

My requirement here is to remove all those objects from the response where the filters are mentioned as "Blank".

So I have used the below code to remove the blanks :

```cs
lst.RemoveAll(x => x.filterOrder.Contains("Blank"));
lst.ForEach(fe => {fe.Details.RemoveAll(r=> r.filterDetails.Contains("Blank"));});
```

This is working perfectly fine.  But now the requirement changed to remove objects based on multiple strings and not single string. Means I'll have something like

```cs
string removeCriteria ="Blank,Blank1,Blank2"
```

I convert this into a list of strings like this :

```cs
List<String> removeList = removeCriteria.Split(",").ToList();
```

Now I have use removeList in the above code instead of hardcoded "Blank". What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12376462/3034273)?

Comment: I would not recommend using `ForEeach` when you just need a regular loop. LINQ is for querying data, not modifying data, so if you want to use LINQ in general, you would create a new list. Replacing `Contains` with `removeList.Any(r => x.filterOrder.Contains(r))` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure if I am missing something here but isn't this a fairly simple ForEeach loop?

```
string removeCriteria ="Blank,Blank1,Blank2"
List<String> removeList = removeCriteria.Split(",").ToList();

ForEach (String toRemove in removeList)
{
   lst.RemoveAll(x => x.filterOrder.Contains(toRemove));
   lst.ForEach(fe => {fe.Details.RemoveAll(r=>r.filterDetails.Contains(toRemove));});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I was not looking for a foreach loop. Was hoping could do it a single line using linq.

Comment: You can but it will look nasty long `removeList.ForEach(toRemove => {lst.RemoveAll(x => x.filterOrder.Contains(toRemove));lst.ForEach(fe => {fe.Details.RemoveAll(r=>r.filterDetails.Contains(toRemove));}); })`

Comment: Will foreach loop effect the performance ?

Comment: This is definitely not ideal but I cannot think much improvement can be made. Unless you're not handling millions of records then there will be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

For a little better performance, especialy  if each parent has alot of child records,  I would suggest to change MattBaran answer a little

```
string removeCriteria ="Blank,Blank1,Blank2"
List<String> removeList = removeCriteria.Split(",").ToList();

//at first remove all parents with children
foreach (var toRemove in removeList)
{
   lst.RemoveAll(x => x.filterOrder.Contains(toRemove));
 }

//after this check the children of remaining records
foreach (var toRemove in removeList)
{
     lst.ForEach(fe => {fe.Details.RemoveAll (r=>r.filterDetails.Contains (toRemove));});
}
```